# MySQL Multi-instance with SAN storage

Tags: mysql, storage-area-network

Two separate MySQL servers (instance) on Windows Server 2008 running concurrent to serve requests. Database files on SAN. Does MySQL supports this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Given that a SAN is just a block device MySQL doesn't care.

What you can't do, even with a cluster filesystem (which, last I knew wasn't in Windows Server) is have multiple instances pointing at the same disk, you could only do a failuover configuration.

Comment: So, I can only have one instance active, the other one just lying idle waiting to take over in case the master instance fail. Thks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Running MySQL directly on a SAN LUN as shared storage does not work, unlike Oracle with ASM.

You can go different directions:

- Running a cluster file system (GFS2 or OCFS) on all nodes, putting the MySQL database files there.
- Using a NAS Server providing the storage via a network file system
- Having one LUN for each server and running MySQL cluster (NBD storage engine)
- Using MySQL replication with shared-nothing-nodes